# Cassandra deleted rows coming back (reappear) when nodes have NTP sync issue

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have 3 nodes cassandra setup and seems like some nodes had time sync issues, that is some nodes 10 minutes ahead of others.

```
CT-Cass2:/root>nodetool status
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.94.1.22  14.15 GB   256          ?       db37ca57-c7c9-4c36-bac3-f0cbd8516143  RAC1
UN  172.94.1.23  14.64 GB   256          ?       b6927b2b-37b2-4a7d-af44-21c9f548c533  RAC1
UN  172.94.1.21  14.42 GB   256          ?       e482b781-7e9f-43e2-82f8-92901be48eed  RAC1
```

I have below table created.

```
CREATE TABLE test_users (
    userid text PRIMARY KEY,
    omavvmon int,
    vvmon int
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 'compaction_window_size': '1', 'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 48000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I can see that in customer setup some of the deleted records coming back and shows writetime(omavvmon) shows writetime of 10 minutes later than the row delete time. I am almost certain that records are coming back due to time sync issue (Because after correcting time its not happening). But when i tried to reproduce  this issue locally it never happens.

1. I set cassandra system time 10 minutes ahead and create row. and writetime shows 10 minutes ahead

> update test_users set omavvmon=1 where userid='4444';

2. I set the system time back to normal, that is 10 mins slower. Then i perform delete of userid 4444.

As i understand, this delete is 10 minutes lesser writetime compared to first creation and i should see records coming back again. But its not happening. Can any help me explain why deleted records coming back in production setup and not in my local setup? Also why cassandra is not showing the record locally even though delete has lesser timestamp compared to insert? Isnt it similar to delete then insert?

In production i check after few hours but local setup i am checking immediately after delete.

Comment: Is it anything to do with gc period or repais, compaction running in production and not running locally?

Comment: Perform a sstabledump and check the writetime of your writes

Comment: Your local setup is on vm? Writetime can be configured from the driver code or cordinator node

Comment: Yes, local setup is on vm. Does it matter?

Comment: The write time may be coming from the driver code which is running outside vm or  time on vm and local machines are different. Anyhow, just do a stabledump you will be able to see write time. C* will always returns the latest record

Comment: If it has to come from driver code then it has to be sent in command right? but we arent doing it so. it should take server time.

Comment: Which timestamp does cassandra use to write to db? is it nodes own time or coordinator node?

Comment: Coordinator node

Comment: What version of C* driver are you using. Go over this link , https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/query_timestamps/